# NDEigensystem to find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of coupled differential equations:

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, code-request, eigenvalues

I would like to numerically solve the following system of coupled differential equations:

```
eq1=h/(2*ma) * PsiA''[x]+ VExt*PsiA[x]+ga*Abs[PsiA[x]]^2 + gab*Abs[PsiB[x]]^2*PsiA[x] == mua*PsiA[x]

eq2=h/(2*mb) * PsiB''[x]+ VExt*PsiB[x]+gb*Abs[PsiB[x]]^2 + gab*Abs[PsiA[x]]^2*PsiB[x] == mub*PsiB[x]
```

The following are known model parameters:

```
h ma mb ga gb gab
```

The term "VExt" is a known function of x, namely:

```
VExt=-P(Cos[3/2*x/L*2*Pi])^2
```

The boundary conditions are the periodic ones, i.e.

```
PsiA[x]==PsiA[x+L]

PsiB[x]==PsiB[x+L]
```

I would like to know how to find eigenvalues

```
mua mub
```

and eigenfunctions

```
PsiA[x]   PsiB[x]
```

Thanks in advance.

For example purposes, you can take:

```
h = 1; ma = 1; mb = 2; ga = 1; gab = 1; gb = 1; L = 4;
```

Comment: Indicate the particular case of functions and parameters. I will show the solution algorithm.

Comment: I've changed my post specifying the form of VExt. Concerning model parameters, what you've chosen is very good. Can you please modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: Can you also briefly explain and comment your code. In particular, I don't understand the role of bc1 and bc2. They seem to be further constraints which I have no reasons to introduce...

Comment: These are the usual conditions for such tasks. To find the eigenvalues, three boundary conditions must be specified, not two.

Comment: Periodic solutions may not exist for every potential.

Comment: I know! But my potential is indeed periodic. So, also the solutions are periodic. That’s why I don’t like bc1 and bc2...

Comment: The solution may be periodic, but the period may not coincide with the period of the potential. And you assume that the periods coincide.

Comment: At first, thanks a lot for your help. Actually, the potential has period $L/3$ and I want my solutions to have period $L$. Forcing PsiA and PsiB to assume value $=1$ in $x=0$ seems to me an additional constraint.

Comment: We have to put something on the border.

Comment: If you put something on the border, you authomatically neglect whole classes of eigenvalues

Comment: I updated the code

Answer (score 2):

I will show the solution algorithm for some set of parameters.

```
h = 1; ma = 1; mb = 2; ga = 1; gab = 1; gb = 1; L = 4; VExt = \
1;
eq1 = h/(2*ma)*PsiA''[x] + VExt*PsiA[x] + ga*Abs[PsiA[x]]^2 + 
    gab*Abs[PsiB[x]]^2*PsiA[x] == mua*PsiA[x];

eq2 = h/(2*mb)*PsiB''[x] + VExt*PsiB[x] + gb*Abs[PsiB[x]]^2 + 
    gab*Abs[PsiA[x]]^2*PsiB[x] == mub*PsiB[x];

 bc1 = {PsiA[0] == 1, PsiA'[0] == 0};

bc2 = {PsiB[0] == 1, PsiB'[0] == 0};

 PSA = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, bc1, bc2}, 
  PsiA, {x, 0, L}, {mua, mub}];
PSB = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, bc1, bc2}, 
  PsiB, {x, 0, L}, {mua, mub}];

FindRoot[{PSA[mua, mub][L] == 1, 
  PSB[mua, mub][L] == 1}, {{mua, -1}, {mub, -1}}]

Out[]= {mua -> -2.84339, mub -> -1.15353}

{Plot[PSA[-2.84339, -1.15353][x], {x, 0, L}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "PsiA"}], 
 Plot[PSB[-2.84339, -1.15353][x], {x, 0, L}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "PsiB"}]}
```

[image: fig1]

In the case of a periodic potential, it is possible to weaken the conditions at the boundary and use a parametric function with 4 parameters.

```
h = 1; ma = 1; mb = 2; ga = 1; gab = 1; gb = 1; L = 1; 
VExt[x_] := -(Cos[3*x/L*Pi])^2;
eq1 = h/(2*ma)*PsiA''[x] + VExt[x]*PsiA[x] + ga*Abs[PsiA[x]]^2 + 
    gab*Abs[PsiB[x]]^2*PsiA[x] == mua*PsiA[x];

eq2 = h/(2*mb)*PsiB''[x] + VExt[x]*PsiB[x] + gb*Abs[PsiB[x]]^2 + 
    gab*Abs[PsiA[x]]^2*PsiB[x] == mub*PsiB[x];
bc1 = {PsiA[0] == A0, PsiA'[0] == 0};

bc2 = {PsiB[0] == B0, PsiB'[0] == 0};
PSA = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, bc1, bc2}, 
  PsiA, {x, 0, L}, {mua, mub, A0, B0}, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]
PSB = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, bc1, bc2}, 
  PsiB, {x, 0, L}, {mua, mub, A0, B0}, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]

 FindRoot[{PSA[mua, mub, 1.9, 1.7][L] == 1.9, 
  PSB[mua, mub, 1.9, 1.7][L] == 1.7}, {{mua, -18}, {mub, -8}}, 
 Method -> "Secant"]

Out[]= {mua -> -17.8395, mub -> -7.76387}

 {Plot[PSA[-17.8395, -7.76387, 1.9, 1.7][x], {x, 0, L}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "PsiA"}], 
 Plot[PSB[-17.8395, -7.76387, 1.9, 1.7][x], {x, 0, L}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "PsiB"}]}
```

[image: fig2]